# Stop Javascript function from firing onload?

Tags: javascript

I've got this function that brings up a pop-up window onClick. However, it's working both onClick and onLoad. Naturally, this would be annoying to the end user to have to exit the window every time they load a page. Does anybody have an idea on how to make this onClick only? Removing the function at end stops the script completely.

```
function showMailingPopUp() {
    require(
        ["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"],
        function(L) {
          L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us4.list-manage.com","uuid":"91363270e58a57510d5d933c6","lid":"b2d7dd4078"})
        }
    );

    document.cookie = 'MCPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
    document.cookie = 'MCPopupSubscribed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;'; 
}

showMailingPopUp();
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `showMailingPopUp();` call at the end?

Comment: Remove `showMailingPopUp();` ?? Is this a serious question or a troll post?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you understand what `showMailingPopUp()` does at the end of the function?

Comment: move the `showMailingPopUp()` to an onclick event

Comment: Removing the function stops it working completely - using an onclick callout in Html does nothing.

Comment: No one said remove the *function*. They said to remove the function call you have. `showMailingPopUp();`

Comment: That's what I do - shoeMailingPopUp(); at the end is removed, but the function stops running onclick.

Comment: @Boomer Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLk37yaz/2/) I made - it shows different ways to call functions. You can either bind with `addEventListener` in JavaScript or define it in a script tag before the onclick DOM element.

Comment: @escapesequence this seems to help, just trying to get it to work live. Thank you!

Comment: @Boomer No problemo! I have submitted an answer, feel free to accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `showmailingPopUp` isn't working with onclick is because it cannot find it. It should either be defined before in a script tag or in JavaScript binding with an event listener.

Here is a solution using JavaScript (adding an event listener to an element so the function will call correctly):

```
function showMailingPopUp() {
    require(
        ["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"],
        function(L) {
          L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us4.list-manage.com","uuid":"91363270e58a57510d5d933c6","lid":"b2d7dd4078"})
        }
    );

    document.cookie = 'MCPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
    document.cookie = 'MCPopupSubscribed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;'; 
}

document.getElementById("element").addEventListener("click", function(){
    showMailingPopUp();
})
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLk37yaz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your function is being called `onLoad()` is because you are calling it using `showMailingPopUp();` at the end of your script.

`onClick` functionality should follow this format:

`<button onclick="showMailingPopUp()">Click me to show mailing popup</button>`